# org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed] while running spoon.sh in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java

When I am running `spoon.sh` file in Ubuntu I am getting the following error:

```
[santosh@sbx data-integration]$ ./spoon.sh
/home/decathlon/Pentaho-5.0.1/data-integration
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:582)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:134)
```

Could anyone please help me in resolving the same?

Comment: It looks like it's attempting to gain access to your display and cannot. What is this application? It's a Java GUI, but where did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (on Ubuntu 14.04). Turned out to be a permissions problem. It was resolved by starting spoon.sh with a user that has permissions to access the graphical environment. On Ubuntu Desktop, the user you use to login is a safe bet. Alternatively, give your Pentaho user the right permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Since it took me some time to find out, I'd like to add that it's possible to set the permission using xhost:

```
xhost +local:
```

Found here : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xhost

Answer (score 0):

If you are access to Ubuntu by VNC, make sure that you are running spoon.sh as same user as VNC server.